# font color of imports does not change after installing Django

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ci1H2.png)

As soon as i installed django, the situation above suddenly happend. The fontcolor that represents imported modules or variables does not change into appropriate ones and remains white. Still Django works but i cannot directly see it does

how can i solve this problem?

attempted to change settings but didn't find any solution
i want to make VSC recognize class and variables precisely

Answer (score 0):

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to switch themes.

[image]

The syntax highlighting of different themes is different, and then switching back to the current theme will refresh the syntax highlighting and display normally.